# List events if the category has occurred multiple times in a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains events. We need to be able to track any trends. For instance, if a Resident has had 2 Medical events within a given date range (which I capture in the where statement) both of those events would be listed. And this has to be done for every resident.

In layman's terms I need to list out every occurrence of a single category that has happened more than once within a given date range for each resident. The subcategory can be ignored, that's a different report altogether.

My table is similar to below;

```
 ID  ||ResidentName||  Category  ||SubCategory ||etc...
-----||------------||------------||------------||
GUID ||Resident1   || Medical    || Complaint  ||
GUID ||Resident1   || Medical    || Abrasion   ||
GUID ||Resident1   || Other      || Other      ||
GUID ||Resident2   || Medication || Wrong Med  ||
GUID ||Resident3   || Accidental || Other      ||
GUID ||Resident3   || Aggressive || Staff      ||
GUID ||Resident3   || Aggressive || Resident   ||
```

What I cannot figure out, is how to get the following result;

```
ID  ||ResidentName||  Category  ||SubCategory ||etc...
----||------------||------------||------------||
GUID||Resident1   || Medical    || Complaint  ||
GUID||Resident1   || Medical    || Abrasion   ||
GUID||Resident3   || Aggressive || Staff      ||
GUID||Resident3   || Aggressive || Resident   ||
```

Note that Resident2 was not listed, because their event only happened once within the given time.

Grouping doesn't seem to be what I want because I need individual rows.
I've tried using `OVER PARTITION`, but that's a new one for me and I'm not really understanding the MSDN description on it. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, there is only so much Tylenol can help.

Comment: Does your table has a Primary Key

Comment: Oh yea, duh. I can't believe I forgot that. I'll update

Comment: Then you can use EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, use `COUNT` with `OVER` clause. Like this:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,ResidentName
        ,Category
        ,SubCategory
        ,etc
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ResidentName, Category) AS EventCount
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE
        DateColumn >= 'start date'
        AND DateColumn < 'end date'
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,ResidentName
    ,Category
    ,SubCategory
    ,etc
FROM CTE
WHERE EventCount > 1
ORDER BY ResidentName;
```

Comment: Eureka! Vladimir you have saved me.Большое спасибо брат!